# Magento 2 admin getting error "not allowed to edit the product's design attributes" during product save!

Tags: product, magento2.3, catalog, admin-panel, product-edit

I have admin user account with limited access. When I am saving a product it is showing an error: `not allowed to edit the product's design attributes` like this screenshot:
[image]

What is the issue & how can it be fixed?

Answer (score -1):

this issue occures when that user's role doesn't have the permission to edit design attributes like this screenshot:
[image: role access]

After that admin user wants to edit a product name or something else store-wise then this issue will occures.

So you need to give permission edit design attributes for that admin user.